# Java LibGDX sprite moving twice as fast as camera

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I've got a class which `extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor` and does the following when you drag around on the screen.

```
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {

    float x = Gdx.input.getDeltaX();
    float y = Gdx.input.getDeltaY();

    if (Store.isGameState) {
        Store.Entity.player.setxMove(x);
        Store.Entity.player.setyMove(-y);
    }
    return true;
}
```

In my player class I have a update method which does the following:

```
    @Override
    public void update() {
        x += xMove;
        y += yMove;
        Store.Camera.Camera.position.set(Store.Entity.player.getXPos() + Store.Entity.player.getWidth() / 2, Store.Entity.player.getYPos() + Store.Entity.player.getHeight() / 2, 0);
        Store.Camera.Camera.update();
    }
```

and a render method which is:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch SB) {
    SB.begin();
    Store.Entity.sprite.setPosition(Store.Entity.player.getXPos(), Store.Entity.player.getYPos());
    Store.Entity.sprite.draw(SB);
    SB.end();
}
```

Which all-in-all works, the camera will move around as will my sprite. However my sprite does not move at the same speed as my camera and I can't for the life of me figure out why this is the case. The sprite moves roughly twice as fast as the camera does, and isn't centered on the player which I'd like ideally.

EDIT:

So in my GameState I have the following:

```
package com.imjoshscott.dataria.states;

import com.imjoshscott.dataria.Game;
import com.imjoshscott.dataria.Store;

public class GameState extends State {

    public GameState(Game game) {
        super(game);
        Store.isGameState = true;
        Store.Entity.getPlayer(game, Store.Entity.getSprite());
        Store.Graphics.getSpriteBatch();
        Store.Graphics.getTiledMap();
        Store.Graphics.getTiledMapRenderer();
        Store.Camera.getCamera();
        Store.Camera.getHudCamera();
        Store.Camera.Camera.setToOrtho(false, Game.GAME_WIDTH, Game.GAME_HEIGHT);
        Store.Camera.HudCamera.setToOrtho(false, Game.GAME_WIDTH, Game.GAME_HEIGHT);
        Store.Camera.Camera.viewportHeight = Game.GAME_HEIGHT / 2.5f;
        Store.Camera.Camera.viewportWidth  = Game.GAME_WIDTH / 2.5f;
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        Store.Graphics.tiledMapRenderer.setView(Store.Camera.Camera);
        Store.Entity.player.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Store.Graphics.tiledMapRenderer.render();

        Store.Entity.player.render(Store.Graphics.SB);
    }

}
```

The Camera stuff in the Store class:

```
public static class Camera {
    public static OrthographicCamera Camera;
    public static OrthographicCamera HudCamera;

    public static OrthographicCamera getCamera() {
        if(Camera == null)
            Camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        return Camera;
    }
    public static OrthographicCamera getHudCamera() {
        if(HudCamera == null)
            HudCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        return HudCamera;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Showing update & render methods

```
public void update() {
    moveCreature();
    Store.Entity.sprite.setPosition(Store.Entity.player.getXPos(), Store.Entity.player.getYPos());
    Store.Camera.Camera.position.set(Store.Entity.player.getXPos(), Store.Entity.player.getYPos(), 0);
    Store.Camera.Camera.update();
    xMove = 0f;
    yMove = 0f;
}


public void render(SpriteBatch SB) {
    SB.begin();
    Store.Entity.sprite.draw(SB);
    SB.end();
}
```

Comment: There's an inconsistency in your question. Title says camera moves twice as fast as player yet in the text you say the sprite moves twice as fast as the camera?

Comment: My bad, edited to be correct. It's the sprite that's moving twice as fast as the camera.

Comment: What type of camera are you using?

Comment: LibGDX's `OrthographicCamera`

Comment: Could you include the code where you initialise the camera please? There's a chance it has something to do with that.

Comment: Edited the initial question to include where the object's created.

Comment: Does changing the viewport size have an impact at all? e.g. don't divide by 2.5 and see what happens.

Comment: It's still the same, just not zoomed in as much that's all. Camera and sprite still moves the same speed / amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** My previous answer is not correct, upon seeing and checking the project I saw this `render()` method for `GameState` class (after looked around for several places but no dice, if ever found this very weird problem again I would direct to this).

```
public void render() {
    Store.Graphics.tiledMapRenderer.render();

    Store.Entity.player.render(Store.Graphics.SB);
}
```

Just one thing we need to add to fix very weird problem is to add the following code

```
Store.Graphics.SB.setProjectionMatrix(Store.Camera.Camera.combined);
```

so we would have

```
public void render() {
    Store.Graphics.SB.setProjectionMatrix(Store.Camera.Camera.combined);
    Store.Graphics.tiledMapRenderer.render();

    Store.Entity.player.render(Store.Graphics.SB);
}
```

That means we need to set projection matrix to current active `SpriteBatch` to properly render stuff. It's also safe to set it before even render the tile as it uses the same camera as of player.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, it works to the extent that the player camera is attached to the player and no longer moves at seperate speeds. However the player is stuck to the bottom left corner of the screen and isn't centered within the camera.

Comment: Ohh @JoshScott , I carefully checked it again. Actually we don't even need half viewport size offset like the code I provided you neither. I tested the code and it works properly. Do you use `Sprite` class to represent player? You said camera is not center like you want, how off or what result you do get?

Comment: Yeah I'm using Sprite to render the image of the player.

The character sprite is at the left bottom corner of the device.

Comment: @JoshScott your original code should work as expect without a need to offset half of viewport again. If you use your original solution, you said it's not centered, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: The initial code I provided within the question has the camera move separately to the sprite. The camera follows the sprite around to an extent however the sprite moves roughly twice the speed as the camera and looks like they're on separate layers / parallaxing in a way.

Comment: You might try to set position of player inside `update()` loop right after you have update `x`, and `y` with those `xMove` and `yMove`. As after touch dragged is done, there might be a case that such gesture didn't set `0` value for both `xMove` and `yMove` and in your code `update()` still keeps update the latest values thus update camera's position **but** not player itself. Also in case of up/down of framerate, player position which drew on screen might not be in synced with camera's. This might explain why it looks like there are 2 separate layers, parallax in feeling.

Comment: I mean `Store.Entity.sprite.setPosition(Store.Entity.player.getXPos(), Store.Entity.player.getYPos());` to move it to be right after you've updated player's position in `update()`. Try to keep `render()` pure dry with no calculation if possible.

Another thing, you could try reset `xMove` and `yMove` via `xMove = 0f;` `yMove = 0f;` at the end of `update()` as you already accumulated those value into player's position to avoid unexpected behavior (I guess you don't intend to do this in game mechanics).

Comment: Sadly this just brings me back to the beginning essentially, camera and sprite move at different speeds despite having the same X/Y.

Updated OP to show current update & render methods, perhaps it is something to do with the 2.5F afterall? My camera has viewport of game height & width / 2.5f?

Comment: though after looking into it, when I remove the 2.5f viewport for the camera, it's still the same however just the map is zoomed out.

to add to my previous comment, if it doesn't make sense. The sprite starts in the bottom left corner and moves around as the screen is dragged, instead of the sprite been int he center of the screen & camera/map follows as it moves

Comment: @JoshScott do you mind send me the project? Maybe upload to somewhere, I'll download it. You can strip out parts that are not relevant for your project privacy and ease in testing. I'll get back to you as soon as I test and solve the problem.

Comment: I've created a public repo which can be found [here](http://git.imjoshscott.com/haxpor/java) - I've removed most if not everything that's not related to the issue above so should be fairly clean to work with.

Thanks a lot for looking into this, really appreciate it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152608/discussion-between-haxpor-and-josh-scott).